# The underlying provider failed on an open while using stored procedure in code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-first, entity-framework-5

I am trying to retrieve data from stored procedure in entity framework code first model. But while I try it gives me an error “The underlying provider failed on an open” for the inner list of data.

```
            using (ProductDbContext dbUserContext = new ProductDbContext())
            {
                listProducts = dbUserContext.Database.SqlQuery<Products>("SP_GetAllProducts");
                dbUserContext.Database.Initialize(force: false);

                var dbProdCmd = dbUserContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
                dbProdCmd.Connection = dbUserContext.Database.Connection;

     //((IObjectContextAdapter)dbUserContext).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();

                dbProdCmd.CommandText = "SP_GetAllProducts";
                dbProdCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                try
                {
                    // dbUserContext.Database.Connection.Open();
                    ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbUserContext).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();

                    dbUserContext.Database.SqlQuery<Products>("SP_GetAllProducts");

                    var prodReader = dbProdCmd.ExecuteReader();

                    listProducts = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbUserContext)
                   .ObjectContext
                   .Translate<Products>(prodReader, "Products", MergeOption.AppendOnly).ToList();
                    prodReader.Dispose();
                }
                finally
                {
                    //dbUserContext.Database.Connection.Close();
                    //((SqlConnection)dbUserContext.Database.Connection).Close();

                    ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbUserContext).ObjectContext.Connection.Close();
                }
                //((IObjectContextAdapter)dbUserContext).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                return View(listProducts);
            }

Stored Procedure:
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetAllProducts]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * FROM [DBO].[Products]
    SELECT * FROM [DBO].[prd1]
    SELECT * FROM [DBO].[prd2]
    SELECT * FROM [DBO].[prd3]
    SELECT * FROM [DBO].[prd4]
    SELECT * FROM [DBO].[prd5]
    SELECT * FROM [DBO].[prd6]
END


Model:
```

Model structure is something like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Products
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<T> prd1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<T> prd2 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<T> prd3 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<T> prd4 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<T> prd5 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<T> prd { get; set; }
        public DbSet<T> prd1 { get; set; }

        public DbSet<T> prd2 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<T> prd3 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<T> prd4 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<T> prd5 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the database you are connecting to? Where is it? Is it installed at all? Are you using a connection string?

Comment: I am using connection string in web.config:
<connectionStrings>
    <add name=" ProductContext " connectionString="Data Source=servername; Initial Catalog= test; User Id= sa; Password= sa; MultipleActiveResultSets = true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: As above we have mentioned our Stored Procedure structure, there are multiple select queries for different tables to fetch records.

If we use join then will it resolve our issues?

Please let me know your thoughts and suggestations.

Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure what is the name of your context. In the first code sample I see `ProductDbContext` but in the last it's `ProductContext`. Now the connection string name is ProductContext which should work for the ProductContext but will not for ProductDbContext. I think the best would be to specify the connection string name explicitly by creating a parameterless ctor in your derived DbContext class and call `base("Name=ProductContext")`